# Is it possible to animate geometry nodes?

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor, geometry-nodes

I would like to insert the F curve from the sound into the Factor parameter in the Node editor **(1.)**. But after adding the keyframe, I don't see this channel in the graph editor. **(2.)**
[image]

I don't know how to display this in the graph editor?

I tried to look elsewhere, but I didn't find anything. I am using Blender 2.92 RC version.

Comment: Is the object with the geometry nodes in question selected?

Answer (score 4):

I believe, there is a workaround if you move the parameter to the Geometry Input node.

[image]

Comment: My reputation wouldn't let me add a comment from Mike Whitefox above, but he has the correct answer. It's also not displaying my upvote (again because of my limited activity). The more in depth explanation is to make a connection from the node's parameter(s) you want to animate to the "Group Input" node (empty socket) then in the modifer settings you set your keyframe (not in the Node editor), then it will show up. Thanks Mike Whitefox you saved me a lot of frustration.

Answer (score 1):

In **Blender 2.92**, parameters are not displayed in the graph editor.

**They are displayed in Blender 2.93**.

Comment: Should be out in a few weeks! https://developer.blender.org/project/view/125/